# Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object - Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, service

The service created in angular is the following:

```
CheckTicket(barcode, codEspec, diaHoraEspec):Observable<Ticket[]>{
      //read ticket
      return this.http.get<Ticket[]>(`${this.checkticket_url}${barcode}?token=${this.token}&codEspec=${codEspec}&diaHoraEspec=${diaHoraEspec}`, httpOptions);
    }
```

This service consumes an API that returns the following response in the console log:

```
{Contador: 11111111, Barcode: "1111111111111", CodEspec: 11111, Espectaculo: "10º ANIVERSÁRIO", DiaHoraEspec: "2019-06-12T21:00:00", …}
Barcode: "1111111111111"
CodEspec: 11111
CodZona: 1111
Contador: 11111111
Desconto: 0
DiaHoraEspec: "2019-06-12T21:00:00"
Espectaculo: "10º ANIVERSÁRIO"
Lugar: "F-2"
Preco: 0
Zona: "Plateia"
__proto__: Object
```

I also have a model component. 
**Ticket.ts**

```
export class Ticket{
    Contador:number;
    Barcode:string;
    CodEspec:string;
    Espectaculo:string;
    DiaHoraEspec:Date;
    Zona:string;
    Lugar: string;
  }
```

The component "read" that is responsible for using this service.

**read.component.ts**
This component works correctly returns the correct information.

```
barcode:string;
codEspec:Number;
DiaHoraEspecs:string;

reads: Ticket[];

  constructor(private ticketlineservice: TicketlineService, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.codEspec = params['CodEspec'];
        this.DiaHoraEspecs = params['DiaHoraEspecs'];
    });
     }

  ngOnInit() { }

onSubmit(){      
    this.ticketlineservice.CheckTicket(this.barcode, this.codEspec, this.DiaHoraEspecs).subscribe(reads => {
      this.reads = reads;
      console.log(reads);
    });

      if(this.reads != [] ){
        this.snackBar.open("Ticket valid!",'', {
          duration: 2000,
          verticalPosition: 'top',
          horizontalPosition: 'end',
          panelClass: ['snack-sucess'],
          });
        }else{
          this.snackBar.open("Ticket not found!",'', {
            duration: 2000,
            verticalPosition: 'top',
            horizontalPosition: 'end',
            panelClass: ['snack-error'],
            });
        }
}
```

**read.component.html**

This is a list element where I want to display the response that is returned by the API and the form where is submitted the barcode to then execute the service.

```
<div class="text-center">
      <form class="mt-3 text-center" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="text-center">
            <input type="text" maxlength="13" name="barcode" class="form-control text-center mt-2" [(ngModel)]="barcode" placeholder="Barcode"> 
          </div>
        </form>

  <div class="text-center">
    <ul class="list-unstyled my-2">
        <li class="btn w-100 bg-success text-center mx-0 my-2 display-block" *ngFor="let read of reads">
          <h3>Bilhete:</h3>
          <p class="h5"> Espetaculo: {{ read.Espectaculo }} </p>
          <p class="h5"> Lugar: {{ read.Lugar }} </p>
          <p class="h5"> Data: {{ read.DiaHoraEspec }} </p>
          <p class="h5"> Código Espetaculo: {{ read.CodEspec }} </p>
          <p class="h5"> Barcode: {{ read.Barcode }} </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**PROBLEM:**
So whenever I submit the form I receive the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I understand that the answer I get from the API is an object, but I want to know if I can turn it into an array. Or should I treat it as an object.
I already tried to remove the `*ngFor="let read of reads"` and in the list elements change to `<p class="h5"> Espetaculo: {{ reads.Espectaculo }} </p>` but the problem is that before I submit the form returns an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Espectaculo' of undefined` and shows the list element empty, I only want to show the list if anything was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check type of reads is array or not before assign

```
 this.ticketlineservice.CheckTicket(this.barcode, this.codEspec, this.DiaHoraEspecs).subscribe(reads => {
          if(Array.isArray(reads)){
              this.reads = reads;
          }
          else if(typeof reads === 'string' ){
              this.reads = null;
          }
          else{
               this.reads = [reads];
          }

          console.log(reads);
        });
```

Change html to

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled my-2">
        <li class="btn w-100 bg-success text-center mx-0 my-2 display-block" *ngFor="let read of reads">
          <h3>Bilhete:</h3>
          <p class="h5"> Espetaculo: {{ read?.Espectaculo }} </p>
          <p class="h5"> Lugar: {{ read?.Lugar }} </p>
          <p class="h5"> Data: {{ read?.DiaHoraEspec }} </p>
          <p class="h5"> Código Espetaculo: {{ read?.CodEspec }} </p>
          <p class="h5"> Barcode: {{ read?.Barcode }} </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: It works, only one problem if doesn't exist it still returns "ticket Valid" and the console.log shows the following error: `Cannot read property 'Espectaculo' of null` and returns the `reads` as null. Also it shows the ticket information empty.

Comment: I update answer for check string type

Comment: The same occurred, the `reads` is null in the console log and also it returns the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Espectaculo' of null` and this: `ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 4, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}`.

Comment: Just a small thing if you don't mind, how can I hide the html `<ul>` element in case the `reads` returns `null` or just show when the `reads` is different from `null`?

Comment: You can use *ngIf condition on ul tag

Comment: So I tried in the `<ul>` element like this `*ngIf="reads"` but always shows the html. I also tried `*ngIf="reads != null"`